# ConEmu: Save split screen configuration

Tags: conemu

I want to save my split screen configuration in conemu.

I know I can build split screen configurations, and save them in predefined tasks using commands like `cmd -new_console:s50H`, but that's not exactly what I want.

I'd like, if it's possible, to access the current configuration of ConEmu, so I could save it, so I won't have to build a script to do so manually.

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? And what do you want to get at last?

Answer (score 10):

You can add a new task, and click "Active Tabs" below the configuration box.

[image: Screen shot for Active Tabs]

Comment: Doesn't work for any complex splits and never has. You can have a perfect complex task even defined or use active and upon start watch your splits suddenly for some reason mosh together. I can demonstrate a working task with 3x3 grid running cmd and 2x2 running POSH that manually opens and splits fine but use that task as the startup, or have those tabs open, go into startup and click to save active as startup and restart and boom the 2nd POSH tab gets added incorrectly to the 1st cmd group and leaves the 1st POSH tab at 100%. Not sure if bug or lack of documentation to config it differently.

Comment: Make sure you open ConEmu (not tabs) as administrator to persist settings

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a direct answer, but you can do this in works in Cmder if you go to `Settings > Startup > Auto save/restore opened tabs`